# Module Plyer: using magnetic sensor

Tags: kivy

I want to test using data from magnetic sensor via module Plyer. After using KivyLauncher script fall down and I obtain next list of warnings:

```
[INFO              ] Logger: Record log in /storage/emulated/0/kivy/MagCompasses/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-05-01_4.txt
[INFO              ] Kivy: v1.9.1
[INFO              ] Python: v2.7.2 (default, Mar 20 2016, 23:30:13) 
[GCC 4.8]
[INFO              ] Factory: 179 symbols loaded
[WARNING           ] stderr: /data/user/0/org.kivy.pygame/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
[WARNING           ] stderr: (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
[INFO              ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] Text: Provider: pygame
[WARNING           ] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "main.py", line 208, in <module>
[WARNING           ] stderr:     MainApp().run()
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android-upstream/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 802, in run
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "main.py", line 115, in build
[WARNING           ] stderr:     self.compasses = Compasses()
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "main.py", line 87, in __init__
[WARNING           ] stderr:     self.enable()
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "main.py", line 91, in enable
[WARNING           ] stderr:     self.sensor.enable()
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android-upstream/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plyer/facades/compass.py", line 18, in enable
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android-upstream/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plyer/facades/compass.py", line 31, in _enable
[WARNING           ] stderr: NotImplementedError
```

Does it mean, that Plyer need module Pygame?

Answer (score 0):

The plyer version in your Kivy Launcher either doesn't support this, or has a bug, or there's some related issue like you're missing an important permission.

You can possibly try including a newer plyer in your app (but this won't work if support still isn't there).

Comment: Thank, I wil try to use your advices.